# What are you supposed to enter for the Account name when adding a GitLab account to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gitlab

This might sound like an obvious and dumb question, but I just cannot signin to a GitLab account (not self-hosted) in order to add it within XCode.

XCode prompts me to enter an account and a personal access token (which I've created from within the gitlab account and granted full read/write access).

But what do I enter for the account? Is that my gitlab username, my gitlab email etc.? No matter what I try, I can't logon within XCode.

The email associated with my gitlab account is `SomeName@somthing.com`, and when I logon to the gitlab website I just enter the `SomeName` portion of it along with my password.
Once logged into gitlab if I display my profile it shows `"My Name"` and underneath that `@SomeName`

If I go to the account section, it displays the full account as:

```
https://gitlab.clt.something.com/SomeName
```

Within XCode I have tried entering the following 6 things as the account name:

```
1) https://gitlab.clt.something.com/SomeName
2) https://gitlab.clt.something.com
3) My Name
4) @SomeName
5) SomeName
6) SomeName@somthing.com
```

But XCode just keeps saying your account or token is incorrect.
The token cannot be incorrect as I only created it 20 minutes ago, so if none of the 6 things above is the correct account name to enter, then what is and where within gitlab do I find it?